# Indexes to create

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have a new table A. It is being joined to existing X,Y,Z tables. As it is a new table, I can create the indexes to improve performance. It has following columns.

```
C1 - nvarchar, 
C2 - NUMERIC, 
C3 - NUMERIC, 
C4  -NVARCHAR, 
C5 - NVARCHAR, 
C6 - NUMERIC, 
C7 - NUMERIC
```

This table is reference in ONLY this query where it is joined the following way:

```
select A.C6, A.C7, ... (other columns from x,y,z table)
From A JOIN X    ON A.C1 = X.C1
       JOIN X X1 ON A.C4 = X1.C1
       JOIN X X2 ON A.C5 = X2.C1
  LEFT JOIN Y    ON (A.C1 = Y.C1 AND A.C2 < Y.C3 AND A.C3 > Y.C2)
  LEFT JOIN Z    ON (A.C1 = Z.C1 AND A.C2 < Z.C3 AND A.C3 > Z.C2)
```

What kind of indexes would help in the performance improvement of this query?

Comment: You really want indexes on `x`, `y`, and `z` more than on `a`.

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of indexes would help in the performance improvement of this query?

Start with only a clustered Primary Key on the table.  Then populate the tables and run the query, outputting the actual query plan.  SQL Server will tell you if you have any missing indexes.

Comment: There is no primary key on the table. Also there is no column which is unique. Is it ok to create a clustered key on C1, C2, C3?

Comment: A key often has multiple columns.  Whatever combination of columns uniquely identify a row.  But the point is that each table has some _manditory_ indexes, typically unique indexes on the keys, and indexes supporting foreign keys.  Start with just those, and then look for missing indexes in the query plan.